# ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED on web deploy

Tags: azure, powershell, msdeploy

We have a powershell script that uses MSDeploy to publish to an azure web app.
Currently the build is failing with the following error :

```
[error]Error Code: ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED
More Information: Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection.  Contact your server administrator if the problem persists.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED.
Error: Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: results. Line 1, position 11278.
Error count: 1.
```

The script has retry logic, which kicks in on this failure, so the deploy itself actually completes fine.
I think I just need to maybe not throw the error, and allow the retry to do its stuff.
Here is the script :

```
$DeployComplete = $false
$AttemptCount = 1
Write-Output "Deploying Files"
while((!$DeployComplete) -and ($AttemptCount -lt 6)){
    try{
        $DeployArgs = "-verb:sync -source:contentPath=""$DeploymentPackageLocation"" -dest:contentPath=d:\home\site\wwwroot\,publishSettings=""$publishProfilePath"""
        $msdeployEC = (Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -ArgumentList $DeployArgs -Wait -Passthru -NoNewWindow -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).ExitCode
        if($msdeployEC -ne 0){throw}

        Remove-Item -Path $publishProfilePath -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $DeployComplete = $true
    }
    catch{
        Write-Output "`tDeloyment did not complete successfully. Attempt : $AttemptCount"
        $AttemptCount = $AttemptCount + 1
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message        
        Write-Output $ErrorMessage
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
    }
}
```

Could I perhaps just remove the try-catch?

Comment: According to you description, seems your build will also fail with same error locally. It's actually related to  code part of your script. Not related to any TFS side configuration.

Comment: Any reason you are not using the Azure App Service deploy task in TFS/Azure DevOps? Why create your own script the task does everything for you and even does transforms.  https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeploymentV4/README.md

Comment: We set up this powershell script so that we can do some extra things in there, most importantly we have some tests that hit the staging slot and check that it is up before swapping the slots over. This allows us to minimize impact on our customers.